# iso - FirebaseCrash - upload-sym error

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

```
Unexpected argument '/Users/saylanc/yazario-ios-app/Pods/ServiceAccount.json'
usage: /Users/saylanc/yazario-ios-app/Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym [-h] [-v] [-w|-e]
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
```

I am getting this error, I followed the guide at the official firebase page.

My bash script :

```
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:xxxxx:ios:xxxx
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${PODS_ROOT}"/ServiceAccount.json
```

Comment: I have the same format, when you run the app on the simulator make sure internet is connected at launch.

Comment: I have internet connection, still getting the same error

Comment: did you add ServiceAccount.json through xcode or finder ?

Comment: dragged it from finder to Xcode

Comment: the last things i can help with, make sure the file name case is like the one you are using ServiceAccount.json, clean and delete derived data.

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of FirebaseCrash.  It looks like you might have an older version of upload-sym.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest version of FirebaseCrash. It looks like you have an older version of upload-sym.

Answer (score 0):

Our app wasn't crashing, but we were getting the following warning.`"Unable to find service account JSON file: ${SERVICE_ACCOUNT FILE}"`

What fixed it for us was to change the script to:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}"/ServiceAccount.json
```

Thought that might help.